# Content field list(text) : using correctly <img>?

Tags: 7, entities, media, nodes

I have a little problem concerning the following :

For a specific content type, I've created a field of type "List(text)", which represents the difficulty of the content ; so in the values I've entered (**I want to attach an icon to each value of that list**) :

```
easy|<img src="[image path]/content_difficulte_easy.png" alt="Easy"> Padawan

middle|<img src="[same path]/content_difficulte_middle.png" alt="Middle"> Jedi

hard|<img src="[same path again]/content_difficulte_hard.png" alt="Hard"> Jedi Master
```

I've checked that the image path is correct, but the images don't appear anywhere...!

Thanks for reading ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this too and it didn't work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248061/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-images-next-to-the-text-on-a-html-dropdown-combob you cannot put images in dropdown box in general (unless you use javascript).  I tried it as a 'Check boxes / radio buttons' widget and it did work.  Maybe that will be a good enough solution for you

Comment: Indeed, it worked with checkboxes. Thanks ! And also thks for the link to image dropdown !  :)